# Windows Phone 8.1 not appearing - Performance and Diagnostics

Tags: c#, performance, windows-phone-8.1

I want to check analyzing of my windows phone project,There are two project in my solution,but when I choose my Windows phone project as startup project, its not appearing in "Performance and Diagnostics" option. How to deal with it?

Comment: From [MSDN blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/03/performance-profiling-on-windows-phone-8-1-with-visual-studio.aspx), this requires Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

Comment: @kennyzx ok thanks!!got it!! The  option is "Start Windows Phone Application Analysis".

Comment: that's great, you can edit your question (adding the VS edition, service pack info and your project type - Silverlight Phone apps) and then answer it yourself and mark it as answer, this can be helpful to others who search for similar questions.

Comment: @kennyzx yeah, thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is here, I got it.The option is "Start Windows Phone Application Analysis".